# Springdoc openapi with webflux: display custom json/yml file instead of generated one

Tags: spring, spring-webflux, springdoc-openapi-ui

I have a simple service-description file open-api.json:

```
{
  "openapi": "3.0.1",
  "info": {
    "title": "OpenAPI definition",
    "version": "v0"
  },
  "paths": {
    "/agents/{id}/plugins": {
      "post": {
        "tags": [
          "api-controller"
        ],
...
  },
  "components": {}
}
```

And I use springdoc-openapi-webflux-ui in my Spring-webflux project:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-webflux-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Is it possible to display existing file instead of generated one?
Any help, thanks!

Comment: what is that you want? You want to display this json in the swagger UI instead of the pretty formatting?

Comment: @AbhinabaChakraborty 
I want swagger to use this file to generate an html page with a description of endpoints.
I tried putting the file in / static, and setting up webflux so that it looked for resources in this folder, but this does not work

Comment: Ok. So your file is under src/main/resources/static directory? or where? (relative to project root)

Comment: @AbhinabaChakraborty yes

Comment: Hey @SashaKorkin It's been quite a while since you asked this question. Any updates from your side? Did you try out the answer I had provided?

Comment: did it work for you?

Answer (score 1):

If your file contains the OpenAPI documentation in OpenAPI 3 format.
Then simply declare: (The file name can be anything you want, from the moment your declaration is consistent)

```
springdoc.swagger-ui.url=/open-api.json
```

Then the file open-api.json, should be located in: src/main/resources/static

No additional configuration is needed.

The property springdoc.swagger-ui.configUrl, can be used for different usage as discussed here, because the structure is different from

- https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/issues/686

Comment: i tried this but it doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 0):

Ok so here is what you need.

1. Inside your *src/main/resources directory*, create a directory called *static*. Inside that place your open-api.json file. (**Note**- The name of the json file can be anything) [ [Here](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/examples/v2.0/json/api-with-examples.json) is a sample open api spec json file ]
2. Add this property in your application yaml:

```
springdoc:
  swagger-ui:
    configUrl: /open-api.json
```

Then start your App and hit the URL http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html

**Note that if spring security is present, you need additional configuration.**

Comment: 1. How to specify open-api.json file if there is application.properties file and not application yaml. 

2. Does the name have to be open-api.json or it can be anything ?

Comment: `configUrl` is not an apropriate parameter. In fact a config is a JSON with the following keys: `configUrl`, `oauth2RedirectUrl`, `url`, `validatorUrl`

To supply a pre-made OpenAPI3 JSON to swagger-ui one needs to use parameter `springdoc.swagger-ui.url`. See @brianbro answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/63668854/3159253